# SVG generation with FOP doesn't work

Tags: java, debian, ghostscript, apache-fop, batik

On one server, and on my Windows laptop, producing PDFs with this method works fine:

http://www.databasesandlife.com/svg-to-pdf/

But on the other server I get this error:

```
org.apache.batik.transcoder.TranscoderException: Error while setting up PDFDocumentGraphics2D
Enclosed Exception:
Error while setting up fonts
    at org.apache.fop.svg.PDFTranscoder.transcode(PDFTranscoder.java:189)
    at org.apache.batik.transcoder.XMLAbstractTranscoder.transcode(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.batik.transcoder.SVGAbstractTranscoder.transcode(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.batik.apps.rasterizer.SVGConverter.transcode(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.batik.apps.rasterizer.SVGConverter.execute(Unknown Source)
```

I have been Googling and searching for hours, but to no avail. What can I do?

I tried installing the following packages but they didn't help:

```
sudo apt-get install gsfonts gsfonts-x11 gsfonts-other batik \
    libbatik-java libxmlgraphics-commons-java  \
    libxmlgraphics-commons-java fop sun-java6-fonts
```

My situation is:

- Debian 6.0.3
- Sun Java version "1.6.0_26"
- JARs: avalon-framework-4.2.0.jar batik-all-1.7.jar commons-io-1.3.1.jar commons-logging-1.0.4.jar fop-0.95.jar log4j-1.2.15.jar xml-apis-ext.jar xmlgraphics-commons-1.3.1.jar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach to solving this problem is in `log4j.properties` I turned up the level to `TRACE`.

There I saw the extra log before the `TranscoderException` that I'd seen previously:

```
2012-02-28 11:51:24,863 DEBUG: org.apache.fop.fonts.FontCache: 
   Writing font cache to /usr/share/jetty/.fop/fop-fonts.cache
org.apache.batik.transcoder.TranscoderException: 
   Error while setting up PDFDocumentGraphics2D
```

Horray for logs! (And writing a log about what the program is about to do, not just once it has done it, so that if the operation fails, then you know what it was trying to do while it failed.)

On Debian, the Jetty webserver runs under the user `jetty` and has its home directory at `/usr/share/jetty/`. However, the `jetty` user does not have write-access to its own home directory, therefore this `~/.fop` directory could not be created.

```
adrian@10770-02:~$ grep jetty /etc/passwd
jetty:x:107:111::/usr/share/jetty:/bin/false
adrian@10770-02:~$ ls -ld /usr/share/jetty
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Feb 28 11:52 /usr/share/jetty/
```

I don't know whether this is by design, or a bug, but creating this directory so that Jetty could write it...

```
sudo mkdir -p -m 0777 /usr/share/jetty/.fop
```

...solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Sincerely it is not a good idea to create such temporary files inside the `jetty` structure from the Debian package. In case of an update, you may get into troubles. Such a cache directory should be located in `/var`, like `/var/tmp` for instance.

According to [documentation](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/trunk/fonts.html#font-cache), FOP is supposed to use the temporary directory in case of failure. Probably your finding deserves a bug report.

Until it is fixed, you should set [`cache-file` option](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/0.95/configuration.html)  Disabling cache with `use-cache` is another way but probably with performance impacts.